# Optimization Problem.

Tags: calculus, optimization

I'm working on some calculus homework, which deals with optimization problems, we have the solution posted for us and when looking over it I got a bit confused. Here's the question:

> An open rectangular box is to be made from a piece of cardboard 8 in. wide and 15 in. long by cutting a square from each corner and bending up the sides. Find the dimensions of the box of largest volume.
>
> [image]

And the formula given to us in the solution is:

$$f(x) = (8-2x)(15-2x)x$$

What I don't understand is why there's an extra $x$? Shouldn't the formula be:
$$f(x) = (8-2x)(15-2x)$$

Thanks in advance, hopefully I made this question clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you fold up the edges of the cardboard after cutting out the corners, you will obtain a box whose height is $x$.  This is where the extra factor of $x$ is coming from.

Comment: Ah thank you, I didn't think of that.